# sed searching from line 182, keyword 'INSERT', print the first match line

Tags: sed

sed searching from line 182, keyword 'INSERT', print the first match line

I have tried with

## cat nova.dump| sed -n '182,/INSERT/p'

all lines from 182 and ended with first 'INSERT' will be printed

Is it possible to do it in sed?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '182,/INSERT/{/INSERT/p}'
```

That's my try.

Comment: No need to repeat the regexp just use the empty one i.e `sed -n 182,/INSERT/{//p}' file` or `sed '182,/INSERT/!d;//!d' file`

Comment: @potong I have tried, but some errors occurred. # sed -n '182,/INSERT/{//p}' nova.dump
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression

Answer (score 0):

Just use awk:

```
awk 'NR==182{f=1} f&&/INSERT/{print;exit}' file
```